# Right and left inverse of an operation in a set

Tags: abstract-algebra, arithmetic

> An operation $R$ is a right inverse of the operation $S$ in a set $A$ if for any elements $x,y,z∈A$ we have $x=yRz$ if, and only if, $y=zSx$

From this, for example multiplication is the right inverse of division (since $x=z·y$ if, and only if, $y=x÷z$) but in what set? $\mathbb R-\{0\}$ right?

Comment: The nonzero reals are one correct answer, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication and division being inverse operations works on $K\setminus\{0\}$, where $K$ is any field. So, for example
$$
\mathbb Q\setminus\{0\},\ \mathbb R\setminus\{0\},\ \mathbb C\setminus\{0\},\ \mathbb F_{p^n}\setminus\{0\},\ \dots
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had to change my question though, because I think the definition of left inverse I gave was wrong. my book give the definition of right inverse of an operation and then it says "the concept of a left inverse of an operation is defined similarly", but how? it says that subtraction is the inverse of addition (so both left and right), so I guess if for any xyz in A, x=y-z ↔ y=z+x but im not sure